# Mapping problem of ASP.NET MVC route with optional URL parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

```
routes.MapRoute("Archive.CityState",
              "Archive/{City}/{State}/{OP1}/{OP2}",
               new { controller = "Archive", action = "CityState", OP1 = UrlParameter.Optional, OP2 = UrlParameter.Optional },
               new { City="[a-zA-Z]+" ,State = @"[a-zA-Z]{2}", OP1 = @"[a-zA-Z]+" , OP2 =@"\d{4}" });


public ActionResult CityState(string City, string State, string OP1, int OP2)
        {
            var x = City; 
            var y = State;
            var OptionalParameter1= OP1;
            var OptionalParameter2 = OP2;
            return View();
        }
```

This can map
**Archive/Remond/WA/Chemistry**

**Archive/Remond/WA/Chemistry/2010**

But not

**Archive/Remond/WA**

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These constraints prevent it from matching what you want:

```
OP1 = @"[a-zA-Z]+", 
OP2 = @"\d{4}"
```

As both parameters are required. Modify your regular expression to accept empty values if you want this route to be able to be matched by `Archive/Remond/WA`. Also remember that only the **last** parameter can be optional (you cannot have two successive optional parameters as this makes no sense).

Comment: Thanks. By removing the constraints, problem immediately disappears.But if the constraint makes the parameter required, why Archive/Remond/WA/Chemistry worked with OP2 = @"\d{4}"?